# How to change beam width in musiXtex?

Tags: musixtex, beams

I'm having trouble with beams. I put text under the staves so I can't use the automated beams.

1. How do I use beams such that they will render in the correct place (the beam now starts too far left)?
2. How do I make the beam thicker so it would cover all the note lines that don't shorten because it's not the automated beam?

I use this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
% packages
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\section{Fee Ra Huri / Omnia}
\begin{music}
\instrumentnumber{1}            % number of instruments
\setstaffs1{1}              % number of lines per instrument
\generalmeter{\allabreve}   % time stamp. meterC is 4/4, allabreve is 2/2 or cut time.
\generalsignature{2}            % sets the key. a number greater than 0 is sharp, smaller than 0 is flat
\startextract
% bar 1
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{mi} \slur iiu2 \cu e \en % mi
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{si} \qlp i  \en % si
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{si} \cl i \en % si
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{si} \cl i \en % si
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{la} \slur igd{1.5} \qu h \en % la
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{sol} \qu g \en % sol
\bar % bar 2
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{la} \qu h \en % la
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{sol} \uptext{\it tr}  \qu g \en % sol
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{mi} \qu e \en % mi
\bar % bar 3
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{re} \qu d \en % re
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{sol} \qu g \en % sol
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{sol} \qu g \en % sol
\bar % bar 4
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{fa} \qu f \en % fa
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{mi} \qu e \en % mi
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{fa} \ibu1f2 \qu f \en % fa
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{sol} \qu g \en % sol
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{la} \qu h \en % la
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{si} \tbu1\qu i \en % si
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{la} \qu h \en % la
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{mi} \qu e \en % mi    
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe unrelated but, your MWE is missing a `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your real problem is that you do not connect the notes to the beam. When I delete the unwanted spaces, I get the first image, which shows that your notes have the normal stems, and the beam starts nicely (accidentally) at the top of the first note's stem, but then slope 2 is not enough for covering the others.
The right code to connect the notes is:

```
\ibu1f2\qb1f\zcn{-7}{sol}\qb1g\zcn{-7}{la}\qb1h\zcn{-7}{si}\tbu1\qb1i
```

[image: image 1, disconnected stems]
[image: image 2, connected stems]

The second image shows that the last stem is a little bit shorter than the first.
Other problems in your examples are:
Your text is placed arbitrarily due to the spaces inserted. As you can see in my images, the syllable always starts on the left of the note. If you want it centered, you could use \ccn (paragraph 17.3 of the musixdoc manual), but it does not align nicely, much more effective (if you do not want to invoke musixlyr) is `\zsong{*text*}` or `\csong{*text*}`, without the need of indicating a hight (see paragraph 23.1). The advantage is that musixtex then uses the notes as measure for the horizontal distances. Text is always tricky in music, at least when you do not tell musixtex how long your text is. I used the various forms in the first measure of the third example.
[image: image 3, text placing]

Another problem is your use of the slurs. The first starts too early. If you want to have it started at the stem of the note, use `\ibsluru0e` and end it before the third (or the second, in case you wanted 1 distance length instead of your manually adjusted 2 lengths) note with `\tslur0c` (the c is the correction to avoid closing at stem hight, see paragraph 10.2 of the manual).
With this code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
% packages
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\section{Fee Ra Huri / Omnia}
\begin{music}
\instrumentnumber{1}            % number of instruments
\setstaffs1{1}              % number of lines per instrument
\generalmeter{\allabreve}   % time stamp. meterC is 4/4, allabreve is 2/2 or cut time.
\generalsignature{2}            % sets the key. a number greater than 0 is sharp, smaller than 0 is flat
\startextract
% bar 1
\Notes\csong{mi}\ibsluru0e\cu e\cchar{-7}{si}\qlp i\tslur0c\ccn{-7}{si}\cl i\ccn{-7}{si}\cl i\ccn{-7}{la}\slur hgd{1}\qu h\cchar{-7}{sol}\qu g\en % sol
\bar % bar 2
  \Notes\zcn{-7}{la}\qu h\zcn{-7}{sol}\uptext{\it tr}\qu g\zcn{-7}{mi}\qu e\en % mi
\bar % bar 3
  \Notes\zcn{-7}{re}\qu d\zcn{-7}{sol}\qu g\zcn{-7}{sol}\qu g\en % sol
\bar % bar 4
  \Notes\zcn{-7}{fa}\qu f\zcn{-7}{mi}\qu e\zcn{-7}{fa}\ibu1f2\qb1f\zcn{-7}{sol}\qb1g\zcn{-7}{la}\qb1h\zcn{-7}{si}\tbu1\qb1i\zcn{-7}{la}\qu h\zcn{-7}{mi}\qu e\en % mi    
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

I get the last example.
[image: image 4, slurs]

Conclusion: musixtex offers a lot of commands to type music nicely, but never use spaces for horizontal alignment, and, please, study the manual well!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the spaces between the start of the beam and the following note.

Use     `\Notes \zcn{-7}{fa} \ibu1f2\qu f \en % fa`

instead of `\Notes \zcn{-7}{fa} \ibu1f2 \qu f \en % fa`

[image: x]

```
\documentclass{article}
% packages
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \section{Fee Ra Huri / Omnia}
    \begin{music}
        \instrumentnumber{1}            % number of instruments
        \setstaffs1{1}              % number of lines per instrument
        \generalmeter{\allabreve}   % time stamp. meterC is 4/4, allabreve is 2/2 or cut time.
        \generalsignature{2}            % sets the key. a number greater than 0 is sharp, smaller than 0 is flat
        \startextract
        \bar % bar 4
        \Notes \zcn{-7}{fa} \qu f \en % fa
        \Notes \zcn{-7}{mi} \qu e \en % mi
        \Notes \zcn{-7}{fa} \ibu1f2\qu f \en % fa changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \Notes \zcn{-7}{sol} \qu g \en % sol
        \Notes \zcn{-7}{la} \qu h \en % la
        \Notes \zcn{-7}{si} \tbu1\qu i \en % si
        \Notes \zcn{-7}{la} \qu h \en % la
        \Notes \zcn{-7}{mi} \qu e \en % mi    
        \endextract
    \end{music}
\end{document}
```

I do not see any note "uncovered" looking at high zoom:

[image: z]

Comment: You, too, do not connect the stems to the beam and thus do not solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what's caused the beam problem in your code.

I can avoid invoking that problem by using the `musixlyr` package, instead of manually putting lyrics.

My solution is like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% packages
%\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{musixtex}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\input musixlyr

\begin{document}
\section{Fee Ra Huri / Omnia}

\begin{music}
\instrumentnumber{1}            % number of instruments
\setstaffs1{1}              % number of lines per instrument
\generalmeter{\allabreve}   % time stamp. meterC is 4/4, allabreve is 2/2 or cut time.
\generalsignature{2}            % sets the key. a number greater than 0 is sharp, smaller than 0 is flat
\setlyrics{lyr1}{
si si la sol mi re sol sol fa mi fa sol la si la mi
}
\assignlyrics1{lyr1}
\startextract
% bar 1
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{mi} \nolyr\slur iiu2 \cu e \en % mi
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{si} \qlp i  \en % si
  \Notes \cl i \en % si
  \Notes \cl i \en % si
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{la} \nolyr\slur igd{1.5} \qu h \en % la
  \Notes \zcn{-7}{sol}\nolyr\qu g \en % sol
\bar % bar 2
  \Notes \qu h \en % la
  \Notes \uptext{\it tr}  \qu g \en % sol
  \Notes \qu e \en % mi
\bar % bar 3
  \Notes \qu d \en % re
  \Notes \qu g \en % sol
  \Notes \qu g \en % sol
\bar % bar 4
  \Notes \qu f \en % fa
  \Notes \qu e \en % mi
  \Notes \Qqbu fghi \en 
  \Notes \qu h \en % la
  \Notes \qu e \en % mi    
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You use an automatically generated beam by saying \Qqbu fghi, which of course gives a nice beam, but which @Toma expressly stated not to have used, and the use of which is not depending on the use of musixlyr. So, of course invoking musixlyr is much better for inserting text under notes, at least in cases like that of Toma, but does not at all contribute to the solution. Besides: you, too, have not deleted all the spaces (before the backslashes) - which musixtex does not like. Maybe you should delete your answer.