# Beam placement with the MusiXTeX package

Tags: musixtex, beams

I have the following code and I don't understand why it renders with the first note outside of the beam. I want to add all the notes to the beam in equal spacing with the correct slope , length and placing of the beams.

Is there a special syntax to indicate the start of the beam other than what I use (taken from the 'Adding notes to a beam' part of the manual) when using this method to add notes to the beam?

code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{music}
  \parindent 0pt
  \instrumentnumber{1}          
  \setstaffs1{1}                
  \generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}{8}}s
  \generalsignature{2}
  \startpiece
    \Notes \zcn{-9}{sol} \ibu1g1 \nbbu1 \qb1{ghi} \tqu1j \en 
  \Endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the macro `\Qqbbu` to add  four notes to a double beam   and the recommendation on how  attach lyrics. (In your code use     `\Notes \zcn{-9}{sol}\ibbu1g1 \qb1{ghi}\tqu1j \en`)

> Lyrics are best handled by the `musixlyr` package by Rainer Dunker.

(section 23.2). See [musixlyr add-on](http://icking-music-archive.org/software/musixtex/add-ons/musixlyr21c.zip).

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input{musixlyr} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \begin{music}
        \parindent 0pt
        \instrumentnumber{1}          
        \setstaffs1{1}                
        \generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}{8}}
        \generalsignature{2}
        \setlyrics{a-liric}{sol la si do} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \assignlyrics1{a-liric} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \startpiece
        \Notes\Qqbbu ghij\en %sol la si do
        \Endpiece
    \end{music}
\end{document}
```

For more notes under the double beam you might use the construction

`\Notes\ibbu1g3 \qb1{ghij}\tqh1k \en`

Notice that there are **no spaces** between the fourth and last note.

Comment: Very good answer, can you add to your answer why using \nbbu1 didn't work as intended? What was the mistake and how should what's in 'Changing multiplicity after the beam starts' part from the manual be used?

Comment: @Toma This site works best one question at a time to benefit other readers. I suggest you ask another question on the subject of using multiplicity.

Comment: @Toma I answered a earlier question of yours. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/635001/how-to-change-beam-width-in-musixtex. Please see if any of the answers are acceptable to you. Or make a comment.